# Get string representing the expression used as function argument in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, unity-game-engine, assert

I'm developing for Unity3D using C#, and decided it would be useful to have an assert function. (In Unity3D, `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert` *exists*, but does nothing.)

As a developer that works primarily in C++, I'm used to assert messages that contain the asserted expression by way of the preprocessor stringizing operator. That is, given a failed assertion of the form `ASSERT(x > 0, "x should not be zero.")`, the message displayed at runtime message can include the text "x > 0". I'd like to be able to do the same in C#.

I'm aware of ConditionalAttribute and DebuggerHiddenAttribute, and am using both (although the latter seems to be ignored by the custom build of MonoDevelop bundled with Unity). While searching for a solution to this problem, I came across three attributes in the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace that seem related to what I'm trying to do: CallerFilePathAttribute, CallerLineNumberAttribute, and CallerMemberNameAttribute. (In my implementation, I use `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` with `fNeedFileInfo == true` instead.)

I'm wondering if there is perhaps any reflection magic (seems unlikely) or attribute magic (seems slightly more likely) that can help me achieve the same functionality as I'm used to in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pass an expression you can get close to the `x > 0` you want:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void Assert(Expression<Func<bool>> assertion, string message, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "", [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    bool condition = assertion.Compile()();
    if (!condition)
    {
        string errorMssage = string.Format("Failed assertion in {0} in file {1} line {2}: {3}", memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber, assertion.Body.ToString());
        throw new AssertionException(message);
    }
}
```

You then need to call it like:

```
Assert(() => x > 0, "x should be greater than 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was posted 10 years ago the C# world has changed a little as of .Net 5 (and .NetCore 3.1) there is a built in attribute which grabs extressions as strings, I don't think Unity supports this yet (as per question) but they have said they are working towards switching from `.Net Framework` to `.Net Core+`.

**[CallerArgumentExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/caller-argument-expression)** The way that this works is that the compiler will see the `CallerArgumentExpression` attribute and look at the parameter that you have specified there, if you haven't explicitly said what the expression is the compiler will take the text that makes up the expression and compile it in statically.

This would be implemented as:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void Assert(bool condition, string message, 
[CallerArgumentExpression("condition")] string expression = null)
{
    if (!condition)
    {
        string errorMssage = $"{message} - '{expression}'";
        throw new AssertionException(message);
    }
}
```

Usage of this would be:

```
Assert(x > 0, "x should be greater than 0");
```

Which would result in an assert message of:

```
"x should be greater than 0 - 'x > 0'"
```